# Using CSS to align toolbar images to center

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have set my margin and padding for the `submenu-img` to align the toolbar images to center but seem it doesn't 100% align to center and when i try restore down the browser window the toolbar align will lose the shape.

I did a demo on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AZdat/

This is the HTML source code

```
<div class="submenu">
<div class="submenu-img"> 
  <a href="abc.com"><div class = "icon-home"></div></a>
  <a href="abc.com"><div class = "icon-groups"></div></a>
  <a href="abc.com"><div class = "icon-members"></div></a>
  <a href="abc.com"><div class = "icon-favorite"></div></a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.submenu {
    background-color: #353535;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.submenu-img {
    float: left;
    position: inherit;
    padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
.submenu-img .icon-home {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.com/a/img607/9549/j3oe.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 56px;
    width: 41px;
    margin: 0 55px 0 0;
    float:left;
}
.submenu-img .icon-groups {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.com/a/img191/1220/9sb7.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 54px;
    width: 49px;
    margin: 0 55px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
.submenu-img .icon-members {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.com/a/img62/4964/6spa.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 54px;
    width: 64px;
    margin: 0 55px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
.submenu-img .icon-favorite {
    background-image: url(http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/7659/ojv5.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 58px;
    width: 78px;
    margin: 0 55px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: how you want to alingn them???serially in center??? or something else??

Comment: You have a margin of 55px on the right of each, how is that attempting to center?

Comment: @RitabrataGautam I would like theme in center but when you restore down the browser windows it doesn't align in center anymore.

Comment: Also, `div` in `a` is illegal markup.

Answer (score 2):

1) Add `text-align:center` to parent (.submenu)

2) Add `display:inline-block;` to child (.submenu-img) and also
   Remove `float:left` from child

3) Remove the right margin on the final icon

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AZdat/7/)**

```
.submenu {
    background-color: #353535;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center; /* add this rule*/ 
}
.submenu-img {

    position: inherit;
    padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
    margin-left: 20%;
    display:inline-block; /* add this rule */
    margin-right: 20%;
}
 .submenu-img .icon-favorite {
    background-image: url(http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/7659/ojv5.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 58px;
    width: 78px;
    margin: 0;     /* Removed margin here */
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: in the fiddle i center the icons - isn't that what the op needs?

Comment: If I could downvote rationally for the urging of users in this manner, I would.